# How to make zsh always show environment variable name instead of the path?

Tags: zsh, tmux, prompt, oh-my-zsh

I have an environment variable set to my projects folder like this:

```
PROJ=$HOME/projects
```

When I want to open a project folder i just type PROJ/project_name and the shell opens the directory and my prompt looks like this:

```
~PROJ/project_name
```

When I opens a new tmux window, it opens a new shell with the prompt showing the full path like this:

```
~/projects/project_name
```

But I wanted it to keep the variable name on the prompt.

How can I configure tmux / zsh (I'm also using oh-my-zsh) to keep using the environment variable when I create new windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the `AUTO_NAME_DIRS` option in your *Zsh* configuration

```
setopt autonamedirs
```

it has to happen before you set `PROJ`.

Alternatively, if you do not need `PROJ` for anything other than switching (and displaying) paths in *Zsh*, you can set

```
hash -d PROJ=$HOME/project
```

### Explanation:

The feature you are using is called "Static named directories". Usually named directories need do be called with a `~` followed by the name of a shell parameter whose value begins with a `/`, `PROJ` in your case.

If `CDABLE_VARS` is enabled (which *Oh-My-Zsh* does by default) the `~` is not really required. That is why you can use `PROJ/project_name` instead of `~PROJ/project_name`. (but it would fail, if there were a directory with the actual name `PROJ`).

As *Oh-My-Zsh* also enables `AUTO_CD` you do not even need to use `cd`. If a command cannot be executed and matches the name of a directory, *Zsh* will `cd` to that directory.

With all named directories lookups may happen in two directions

1. does a given name point to a directory (e.g. does a parameter contain a path starting with `/`)?
2. does the current directory have a name?

While the first kind of lookup happens automatically when an argument starts with `~` (or in some cases and enabled `CDABLE_VARS` even without), the second kind (which is used for the prompt) requires the directory to be listed in the directory hash table (`hash -d` for a listing of that table). On a freshly started *Zsh* this hash table is usally empty. It will then be filled with data acquired when doing `~` expansions.

In your original shell `PROJ` has been successfully expanded to `$HOME/projects` and so the directory hash table now contains `PROJ=$HOME/projects` (where `$HOME` is replaced with your actual home directory path). *Zsh* can now look it up for its prompt. When you start tmux, a new shell is started and the directory hash table is again empty, thus the name is not replaced in the prompt.

With `AUTO_NAME_DIRS` an entry in the directory hash table is created immediately when a parameter is set to a value that starts with `/` (or it is removed if the new value does not start with `/`). You can also add manually to the directory hash table with `hash -d NAME=PATH`.

Comment: It's working now. Thanks for the complete response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the AUTO_NAME_DIRS option in your Zsh configuration

```
setopt autonamedirs
```

> https://wikiguide.tips/